# setTimeout not adding a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, settimeout

This is my code:

```
function transition(index){
    $("#right-panel").find("img").each(function(){
        if ($(this).index() === index){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).fadeIn(750);
            }, 100000000);
        }else{
            $(this).fadeOut(750);
        }
    });
}
```

For some reason, the setTimeout in the function is not causing a delay for the fadeIn. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I rather suspect the fadeIn isn't happening at all - please confirm?

Comment: Why a 28 hour delay? Have you tried a smaller (reasonable) value?

Comment: Consider caching those images (so that you don't have to query every time).

Comment: @Alnitak the fadeIn definitely is happening

Comment: @Sime no practical reason, just for illustrative purposes, yes i tried a smaller value

Comment: I don't see how that `fadeIn` would work at all; the `this` in there refers to the window, does it not? If you replace the `fadeIn`-call with an `alert('test')`, does the alert show up?

Comment: @Supr yes, that's what I was alluding to - his `this` is incorrect in the callback so it shouldn't be possible for the `fadeIn` to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` in the `setTimeout` callback isn't the same as outside it.

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function(){
    $(self).fadeIn(750);
}, 100000000);
```

Although you could just use `.delay()`.

```
$(this).delay(100000000).fadeIn(750)
```

---

Overall a better approach would seem to be to use `.eq()` to grab the one you want to `.fadeIn()`, and `.fadeOut()` the rest.

```
function transition(index){
    var images = $("#right-panel").find("img");// get all the images
    var fadein = images.eq(index)
                       .delay(100000000)
                       .fadeIn(750); // fadeIn the one at "index"
    images.not(fadein).fadeOut(750); // fadeOut all the others
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need setTimeout at all?

```
function transition(index){
    $("#right-panel").find("img").each(function(){
        if ($(this).index() === index){ // did you check this statement?
            $(this).delay(100000000).fadeIn(750);
        }else{
            $(this).fadeOut(750);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just a note - delay uses setTimeout.. one benefit in using delay is not to worry about this reference.

Comment: @SKS           I meant it specifically for his example.